# How can I deploy an Angular image and have its configuration change according to the environment's environment variable?

Tags: angular, docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I have a project in Angular. This project is almost ready, and I'm currently configuring the deployment aspect to GCP.
The deployment is already set up and working perfectly in the project, but I need to make some automatic adjustments so that it recognizes the environment it's in.

Currently, my deployment workflow is as follows:

- In the build_options file (which contains the commands to be executed in the Jenkins pipeline), I change the "npm run build" command to the one that includes the configuration for the target environment. For example: "npm run build --configuration=qa."
- Once the configuration is changed, I run the pipeline in Jenkins, and it builds with the configuration for that environment, deploying through dev until it reaches QA.
  PS: If I need to deploy to production, I would follow the same process, changing the command.
  These environment configurations include different endpoints depending on the environment.

So, what's the problem here? The problem is that all the previous environments would be configured with the final configuration build. In other words, if I want to deploy to production, both DEV and QA would have those configurations because they share the built image, which was created when passing to DEV for the first time.

Therefore, the idea I need to address is to read an environment variable that is present on the server (environment) and have Angular adopt the appropriate environment configuration based on that variable.

I have some doubts about this:
If Angular requires a build before deployment, does that mean the configuration cannot be changed while the image is being passed between environments?
How can I make Angular, similar to how it's done in Java, read an environment variable and have its configuration endpoints change accordingly as it goes through different environments?

These are my doubts since I have never deployed the same image to different environments before.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Angular is compiled once and then whatever was in the environment files at the time is used.

The reason it doesn't work the same as Java where you take the configuration files at runtime is because you are running the Angular app (mostly) on the browser of the user. Unless you are using server side rendering, your container only serves static files. The whole framework is built around this assumption.

What you can do instead of having the container build the angular project is having the container run the serve command. The build process of the container should only contain the npm install and the run command should be ng serve.

For example:

`ng serve --configuration=qa`

---

On a side note, I am not sure what is gained by creating an image for the angular project since you are simply serving static files. You can use firebase hosting or google cloud hosting to do the same. In backend you can have multiple instances of the container for load balancing, but this isn't the case here since its runs on the browser of the user.